# Azure VM Domain Verification

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I have an Azure VM let's say `myvm.cloudapp.azure.com`. It is accessible using `http://myvm.cloudapp.azure.com` . Now I wanna make it secure `https://myvm.cloudapp.azure.com`. I have added certificate `App Service Certificate`, now I need `Domain Verification`.

[image]

How can I verify the domain?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I verify the domain `myapp.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't verify **myvm.cloudapp.azure.com** as you don't own it, Microsoft does.  Domain verification is used to bring your own custom domain name (e.g. foo.com) to Azure, not to verify default URL's used in the system.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57327603/can-i-get-ssl-certificate-for-website-running-in-azure-vm-at-westeurope-cloudapp

Comment: I have used third part service instead of Azure Certificate Service